# Wordpress : 404 on author page using custom permalinks and pagination

Tags: pagination

I have some author pages in my theme (using a modified version of the UDesign theme and the Pagenavi plugin. Pagination works on the blog, but not on the author pages. I'm getting 404's on the author page urls.

This works: xxxx/author/dr-fiona-nd/

This does not: xxxx/author/dr-fiona-nd/page/2/

Both of these work: xxxx/blog/ xxxx/blog//page/2/

Where do I start on this? I've seen lots of posts about custom content types, but this is a standard post. I've seen other information on adding custom rewrite rules and endpoints, but I'm thinking there's probably some other standard CMS based solution for this, am I wrong?

Looking for some direction, thanks for any help!

Comment: Deactivate the Pagenavi plugin. and try id again.

Comment: if i Deactivate the plugin, the paging is hidden and not show

Comment: Check out this post http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-34-broke-my-paginaton-setup?replies=20#post-2891468   maybe could help you.